# Показать файл на хостинге только авторизованным

Tags: .htaccess, php

Приветствую.

Собственно, нужен или совет в инете, для которого у меня не хватает ума загуглить (слов таких не знаю), или объяснение, желательно с кодом, как реализовать следующее:

Имеем - на хостинге 2 файла, '.htaccess' и, в папке с ним, 'разбогатеть.pdf'. Пользователь может на сайте находиться как авторизованный, так и не авторизованный. И может в адресе сайта вбить этот файл (разбогатеть.pdf).

Возможно ли при обращении к файлу настроить '.htaccess' так, чтобы он перекидывал на определенный файл php, в который передавался адрес файла (разбогатеть.pdf, обанкротиться.pdf, счастье.pdf,..), и уже из настроек этого php-файла был доступ к файлу на хостинге, или нет.

P.S. Да, уже искал подобное. Выхожу только на лекции о том, что такое авторизация, что такое PHP, и как на время закинуть файл в определенную директорию со сложным именем (реального примера, к сожалению, не видел).

```
//.htaccess
чудо проверка через chudo.php

//chudo.php
if($autorized==true){
    как то разрешить показать файл
}else{
    показать картинку с печальным котом
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все файлы закидываем в папку, htaccess запрещаем просмотр папки.
Функция скачивания примерно такая: )

```
function download_file($file){
  $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
  switch ($extension) {
    case "txt": $ctype="text/plain"; break;
    case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
    case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
    case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
    case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
    case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
    case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    default: $ctype="application/force-download";
  }
  header('Content-Type: '.$ctype.'; charset=utf-8');
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".file);
  ob_clean();
  readfile($_GET['file']);
  exit();
}

if($autorized==true){
   downloadfile($path_to_file);
}else{
    print $grampy_cat;
}
```

**Обновление**

Как вариант: список имен файлов хранить в БД, имя файла получать по ID.
Пример:

```
http://host/download.php?ID=10

$id = $_GET['id'];
$path_to_file = get_file_name_from_mysql($id);
```

Comment: Функция гениальная! Сработала, пойду разбираться, почему файл 0 байт, но это уже, скорее, из-за моего хостинга. А, да, файл реально 0 байт )

Comment: @mixalef, сервер может "объявить" размер файла с помощью заголовка `Content-Length: %filesize%`, где %filesize% - размер файла в байтах (результат функции filesize, примененной к файлу).

Answer (score 0):

Для [nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/) есть замечательный модуль [`secure_link`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html), который проверяет подпись, с которой к нему пришёл пользователь, прежде чем отдать контент.

Т.е. сценарий: php генерирует суперссылку, которая действительна, скажем, всего 1 час. И чел по этой ссылке может скачать файл.

Под Apache такого модуля не знаю, но вдруг вы поставите перед Apache проксирующий nginx или решитесь полностью перейти на этот более лёгкий и мощный веб-сервер?